# Format value from dictionary

Tags: python, selenium

I need to define a selector containing a variable. The selector is quite complex and will be used on multiple places. There is only one part of the selector that needs to change with every use.

What I want to do is:

```
selectors = {"edit user": "xpath=//*[@id='{}']"}
...
username = "johndoe"
self.click_element("edit user".format(username))
```

Is it possible to format the value? If yes, how?

Comment: You should learn basic python, like dictionary, string format, to grasp how things work
anyway, dictionary is key value, so you need to format it to something like 
`path = selectors['edit user'].format(username)
self.click_element(path)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
selectors = {"edit user": "//*[@id='{}']"}
...
username = "johndoe"
self.click_element(selectors["edit user"].format(username))
```